# Selenium test reporting, my way

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, c#, test-report

Below is a sample test case which I wrote on my test suite.

In my project i need to be more focus on test reporting, so I thought in storing the test Pass / Failed status on SQL data table.

Then I can use some 3rd party tool to generate the report by referring to the SQL data table.

Any suggestions?

```
   [TestMethod]
        public void Validate_Availability_Of_Identity_Selector_Buttons()
        {
            string TestCaseName = "Validate Availability Of Identity Selector Buttons";
            AvailabilityElm elm = new AvailabilityElm();
            try
            {
                Assert.IsTrue(elm.IdentitySelectors.Displayed == true);

                AddtoSQL(TestCaseName,"Pass","");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

                AddtoSQL(TestCaseName,"Failed",e.ToString());
            }

        }
```

I have used Extended report in the past but I feel I need to add more lines of codes to the test steps if I'm moving with extender reports.

This is how my SQL table looks like :

```
command.CommandText = "  INSERT INTO [dbo].[AUStagAdminPanelTestData]([TestcaseName],[Status],[Info])VALUES(@TestcaseName,@Status,@Info)";
```

Comment: Could you clarify exactly what type of advice you are looking for? Is it a technical one (on how to use the SQL data ) or a processual one (how should you design the report)? 

In both cases, you should specify the target public of these reports:

- The testers that write the automated suite?
- "Non-techinical" QA?
- Devs?
- Business representatives?
- A bug report tool (that will log the failures automatically)?

This information interferes directly on the type of report you want.

Answer (score 1):

I have done something similar in the past, but not in the test itself. Most xUnit test-frameworks have SetUp() and CleanUp() functions. This seems a better place to handle this. Primary as you [do not repeat yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) in each test-case. It will be easier to add more fields for your report when needed.

For C# and MS-test this would like something like this:

**[TestInitialize]**:

Instead of your example I added the test to the database in the `[TestInitialize]` step. [TestInitialize] is run for before each test is run. Also I included a start Timestamp field in the database.

You can use the Test.Name for the name of the test instead of hard-coded `"strings"`

```
string testMethodName = TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Name;
```

**[TestCleanup]**:

In the `[TestCleanup]` I would update the record with pass/fail data, fail-count and an end-timestamp.

```
if (TestContext.CurrentTestOutcome.ToString() == "Failed") {
  //Do Something
}
```

With the timestamps you can also see how long the test takes and when they started.

**Re-run**:

We used this data in a script to select test-cases to re-run slow UI tests after a fail. We would re-run each test up-to three times, this because some of the tests would be flaky, but we did not want to research them everyday.

**More reads:**

- Structure of Unit Tests: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182517(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: \wow..I was pretty much aware about test attributes and i was wondering why i didnt use [TestCleanup] to set pass / fail data.Thanks a lot for mention it.